# Long Running Task Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a website, and I have an administrator page. The admin will have to run a reporting task, meaning that, the task will iterate all the records fetch information and generate a pdf file. Now this will be heavy on the app and the database.

What is the usual approach for it ? Should I have a button that calls a method of a class or should I have a rake task? I heard that HTTP GET requests have a limit and if the report generation takes more than that then it kills the request.

I would like to use `send_data(....)` so the user is given a nice download pop up box when the report is done. Will it be better to use a mailer and email it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have similar functionality in our Rails apps at my job.

We have one URL/action that initiates the request to generate the PDF file, and returns right away saying the request was started successfully.

Then we have another action that we can poll with AJAX that returns whether or not the report is complete, and when it is complete, it gives the user the PDF.

The actual generation is done by a [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) worker which is not subject to the webserver timeout.